# Why doesn't run imported js file when i come from another component with routerLink?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What I want to ask seems confused in the title. I agree with you. But I want to explain.
Most likely, the answer is simple, but I've been trying for hours.

Imported javascript file running when i reload page manually. Everything is ok. I imported like this;

```
import * as myjsFile from '../assets/js/jquery.blabla.js';
```

But when i came from the my menu in homepage with **routerLink** like this;

```
<a routerLink="/page2"></a>
```

It just seems to be loading the HTML. Is this a bug or should it be? Is there any solution except reload all page ?

Comment: Where are importing `import * as myjsFile from '../assets/js/jquery.blabla.js';`? in the component?

Comment: Yes, i imported in the component's ts file.

Comment: try to import it from main.ts file

Comment: I tried, this is also not running js file again.